# body not fitting windows size in html5boilerplate or normalize.css?

Tags: html, html5boilerplate, css

I just tried boilerplate and recognized that the body area is not fitting the whole page.
I made a red body background, so you can see the difference.

Boilerplate normal (body was ending with content)

Boilerplate without normalize.css (body fits whole page)

Is this normal and wanted through the normalize.css and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal because in normalize.css the height and width of body / html element is not set. Set it to 100% and it will work as You want.

```
body,html{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```